# Javascript case-insensitive matching and replacing?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I need to be able to find certain words (by 'word' I mean a **set of characters**) in a string (case insensitive) and if they match, I need to insert a symbol after the first letter of that particular set of characters. I can't use search replace, as that would not preserve the case.

Example:

> Brown brownies are in an oven.

If the word I'm looking for is `brown`, and the character I want to insert is `*`, the result should be:

> B*rown b*rownies are in an oven.

What is the best way to do so in **JS**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function astAfterFirstLetter(words) {
  var re = new RegExp("\\b(?=" + words.join("|") + "\\b)(\\w)(\\w*)", "gi");
  return function (str) { return str.replace(re, "$1*$2"); };
}

astAfterFirstLetter(["brown", "cow"])("How now brown cow!")
```

produces

```
How now b*rown c*ow!
```

Comment: Just add `i` flag to make it case insensitive as per OP

Answer (score 7):

Regex with option 'ig' does the trick.

```
"Brown brownies are in an oven.".replace(/(b)(rown)/gi, "$1*$2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, something like:

```
var re = /(B)(rown)/gi;

console.log("Brown brownies are in an oven".replace(re, "$1*$2"));
```

Comment: This has to be more universal, not just for a particular word/string combination.

Comment: Like how? You can create your regex pattern dynamically, if that helps.

Comment: What is `[\w+ ]` supposed to achieve?  There is nothing that requires matching a plus sign, word character, or space.

Comment: It was just to give an idea as the OP's post wasn't about anything in specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'Brown brownies are in an oven.'
var s = 'brown';
var r = '*';
var re = new RegExp('('+s.substr(0,1)+')('+s.substr(1)+')','ig');
log(str.replace(re, '$1'+r+'$2'));
```

But you will need to watch `s` for the characters that have some special meaning to regular expressions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp) and will need to take care setting `r` too. Will fail also if `s`'s length is less than 2.